# Autoscrolling a DIV element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an auto overflowed DIV on my page, what i want to do is to make it start scrolling slowly towards the end of items of the DIV on page onload.

is that easy u think ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#divID").animate({'scrollTop': '600'}, 5000);
```

For instance.

Comment: i just have a problem, it doesnt scroll until the end, just stops after somewhere, any idea?

Comment: well, value of 'scrollTop' within .animate says, how many pixel it is supposed to scroll. You can calculate that value or just increase it static.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Use the `.load()` event in jQuery to install a timer which updates the scroll position of the DIV using [`.scrollTop()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)